# Microsoft Office 2013 windows template

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, templates, office-2013

I want to make a template like the one used or Microsoft Office 2013 Preview:

[image]

Could anybody give me some tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 2013 Preview has an interface very similar to Metro. I think you should see this article: [Building a Metro UI with WPF](http://nikosbaxevanis.com/2010/12/01/building-a-metro-ui-with-wpf/) and look for any wpf template that make the controls looks like a metro application. Take a look to this [Nuget Package](http://nuget.org/packages/MetroWPF/0.2.6.0). Hope this information could helps you to start...